# I want to build a workflow for my company how to do it with email?

Tags: workflow

When I get for my company https://www.glansbeton.be a email I repond with a mail.  The problem is that I don't have a good way to follow up my sended emails.  Is there a way to follow this up without a CRM system?  At the moment the mails wil not be followed up.   I want to make the following up automatic but I am searching of a way to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Wording is a little unclear, but if I understand you correctly. you should be able to accomplish this with either mail rules.

For mail rules with Outlook:

1. Create new rule
2. Click "Advanced"
3. Check the box next "Sent to" and choose your email address
4. Click "flag message for follow up" and pick your relative date
5. You can also automatically reply using a template
6. Click Finish

For more detailed control, if in an M365 environment, you can use Power Automate.